# Maintain state of Accessory view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationitem, accessoryview

I have a dynamic table in which user can add & delete the data. The table displays the shopping list. If the shopping is done user should be able to tick the desired item and should be able to untick as well, I have achieved this by setting accessorybutton to it. However, the problem comes wen I delete a row from it, the cell gets deleted however the acessory button attached to that cell remains in the same state.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   if (cell.accessoryView == nil)
   {    
    cell.accessoryView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]]; } else { cell.accessoryView = nil; 
   }
}
```

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    
   
    if (cell.accessoryView == nil)
    {
        cell.accessoryView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]];

    }                                 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Because `UITableView`'s typically reuse instances of the `UITableViewCell`'s, you must ensure your '`-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method properly sets all attributes of the cell. Else stale data can persist. I'm guessing this may be your problem, lacking a complete look at your code.

So, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString*    cellIdentifier = @"TheCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell*    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    ShoppingObject* shopping = [self.myShoppingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView*    accessoryView = nil;

    if (shopping.isDone) {
        accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]];
    }

    cell.accessoryView =  accessoryView;

    return cell;
}
```

It obtains the cell, either by from the reuse cache or by creating a new one. Then it checks the state of your data model to see if if shopping is done or not for the object being represented in that row, and if shopping is done gives you your image. Note that is shopping is not done, there is no accessoryView created, so whatever the state of the ShoppingObject is being represented at that table row, the accessoryView for that cell will be set correctly.

So what I'd probably then do in your `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` would be to simply `-reloadData` on the table to ensure everything updates correctly.

Comment: well there isn't a method which checks the shoping is done or not, its user's choice to put a tick if he/she completes the task mentioned in shopping list.

I mean I can't determine the the tick to be displayed, it needs to be displayed wen the row is selected.

Comment: So what is keeping track of your data? The GUI itself?

Comment: user can add n delete random thing in his list. I he's done with the shopping, he/she shud be able to put a tick on it.

Comment: That's fine, but what keeps track of the stuff in the list? The UITableView GUI itself? Do you have some sort of data model? I would assume you do, since I reckon you allow them to enter something like the name of the task. Why wouldn't that object also keep track of the rest of the data state, like the task was completed or not?   Regardless, the point remains: you need to ensure the cell.accessoryView is always set accordingly in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, because it's likely the cell is being reused and that particular cell instance has "stale" data that you're not clearing out.

Comment: how do i remove this "stale cell"

Comment: You cannot, because of cell reuse (the -dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier: mechanism). What you must do is ensure the cell instance you get is fully configured as you need it. So the cell.accessoryView is always set to something, just what that something is depends upon the state of your data model (set to nil if "not done shopping", set to your tick_btn image if "done shopping").

Comment: Finally managaed to do it...As John Daub said, I had to maintain it....I maintained it in my database by creating a method which cud keep track of clicked button's index n the index of the array which holds the text to be displayed on table's cell..! Thankx to my senior...she helped me doing that..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the selected items

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   if (cell.accessoryView == nil)
   {    
    cell.accessoryView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]]; 
    [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
   } 
   else { 
   cell.accessoryView = nil; 
   [self.checkedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
   }

}
```

**Edit**

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

// Do other stuffs

cell.accessoryView = nil;

if ([self.checkedIndexPath containsObject:indexPath]) {
   cell.accessoryView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]]; 
  }  

}
```

Comment: what is checkedIndexPath ?

Comment: just a NSMutaleArray to store the indexPath of selectedItems

Comment: before the for loop.. set the cell accessory view to nil.. cell.accessoryView = nil

Comment: @anil...tried using this...but wen i delete a row all the accessory views turns nil..!

Comment: How you declaring  checkedIndexPath array.. check the array is get releasing? when you deleting a row  cellForIndexPath will calle right?  put a break point in the accessoryView checking section and do a check

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I added
`if ([mutearr containsObject:indexPath])
 {
 NSLog(@"mute arr size %i",mutearr.count);
  for (int i = 0; i<=mutearr.count; i++)
   {     cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]];
}`

In didSelectRow
` if (cell.accessoryView == nil)
    { cell.accessoryView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_btn"]];
        [mutearr addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    { cell.accessoryView = nil;
        [mutearr removeObject:indexPath];
    }`

Comment: just log the mutearr in cellForRow

Comment: Finally managaed to do it...As John Daub said, I had to maintain it....I maintained it in my database by creating a method which cud keep track of clicked button's index n the index of the array which holds the text to be displayed on table's cell..!
Thankx to my senior...she helped me doing that..!